# python package for distributed auction simulation

Tags: python, simulation, distributed

Does anyone know of a package that allows for a distributed agent-based double auction simulation?

I've looked at SimPy, but that's a discrete-event simulator and difficult to get working in a distributed fashion.

regs,

Vivek

Answer (score 2):

You're welcome to try my own [GarlicSim](http://garlicsim.org). If I understand your need correctly, it will work well for you.

[The official website is here](http://garlicsim.org), [the documentation is here](http://docs.garlicsim.org), and [there's a blog here](http://blog.garlicsim.org/).

If you'll need help or have questions, you can [email me directly](http://mailto:cool-rr@cool-rr.com) or use the [mailing lists](http://docs.garlicsim.org/misc/mailing-lists.html). I'll help you get your double-auction simpack up and running.